# Update Java Application from GitHub Releases

Tags: java, git, github, auto-update

I am currently working on a small java-project for mostly private use (A communicator in LAN-Environments to allow text based communication in my home with my roommates). I use this project to get used to Github and git based development. I've implemented a small self-update feature that downloads the latest version from my Dropbox if the local one is out of date. However, since the .jar is included in the Github-releases I asked myself if there is a way of updating the program from there. I don't want to update the .jar in my Dropbox every time I make a new release.

Thanks

Comment: Well conceptually it's obviously change the path that the updater uses from Dropbox to Github. Without more details, it's hard to know what you're asking for

Comment: The Updater uses always the same link to update the file, however, the link to the .jar from the github release download changes with every release (it contains the release name).